# Finding all the variants to find the convergence of Gauss-Seidel iterative method.

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, approximation, matrix-equations

I have the following system of linear equations.

***$\ 4x+y+z+t=6$***
***$\ -x-3y+z+w=6$***
***$\ 2x+y+5z-w-t=6$***
***$\ -x-y-z+4w=6$***
***$\ 2x-z+w+4t=6$***

We are supposed to find the variants of the above system for which the Gauss-Seidel method converges. I tried performing row operations to it, but it yielded no results, to the best of my ability. The matrix, with w and t, for me comes to be:

*[4 1 1 1 0 1]*
*[-1 -3 1 1 0]*
*[2 1 5 -1 -1]*
*[-1 -1 -1 4 0]*
*[2 0 -1 1 4]*

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong and what one particular variant of this system could be?

Edit: I do know that the system in its original form does yield convergence, but the task is to find other forms as well.

Comment: Variants as in with the rows being swapped or manipulated in such a manner that the system remains consistent, but is also diagonally dominant (which is a requirement for a square matrix to converge using the Gauss-Seidel method)

Comment: The original question is:
Consider the following system of linear equations.
4x+y+z+t=6||  
-x-3y+z+w=6||
2x+y+5z-w-t=6||
-x-y-z+4w=6||
2x-z+w+4t=6||
Write all possible arrangements of above system so that Gauss Seidel iterative technique converges.